# How can i pass username and password int http req

Tags: flutter, api, dart, http

Recently I have to make login to ubnt(UNifi) devices from flutter application

so I must pass user and password into URL

this is my code :

```dart
const url = 'http://10.66.5.8/login.cgi?uri=/';
var res = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: {
  'username': 'ubnt',
  'password': 's11n',
});

if (res.statusCode == 200) {
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
} else {
  print(res.statusCode);
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Error')));
}
```

I try with API HTTP but no result

Comment: What happens?  Do you see the error message?  If so, what is printed?

Comment: You need to be more specific about describing the problem you're having. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting, as was suggested when you created your account. I'd suggest you pay special attention to [ask].

Comment: there is no response from url just I want to login in this URL by using flutter